# Unrecognized selector in XCTest test

Tags: swift, xctest, xctestcase

In this code

```
class MyXCTApplicationLaunchMetric: NSObject, XCTMetric {
    let myLaunchMetric: XCTApplicationLaunchMetric

    override init() {
        myLaunchMetric = XCTApplicationLaunchMetric(waitUntilResponsive: true)
        super.init()
    }

    // XCTMetric conformance
    func willBeginMeasuring() {
        myLaunchMetric.willBeginMeasuring()
    }

    // XCTMetric conformance
    func didStopMeasuring() {
        myLaunchMetric.didStopMeasuring()
    }

    // XCTMetric conformance
    func reportMeasurements(from startTime: XCTPerformanceMeasurementTimestamp, to endTime: XCTPerformanceMeasurementTimestamp) throws -> [XCTPerformanceMeasurement] {
        try myLaunchMetric.reportMeasurements(from: startTime, to: endTime)
    }

    // NSObject conformance
    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        self
    // have also tried returning MyXCTApplicationLaunchMetric()
    // and MyXCTApplicationLaunchMetric(myLaunchMetric) when provided    
    // an init that accepts that param. 
    }
}
```

When is called in

```
final class PerformanceUITests: XCTestCase {
    func testLaunchPerformance() throws {
        if #available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 7.0, *) {
            let options = XCTMeasureOptions()
            options.iterationCount = 1

            measure(metrics: [MyXCTApplicationLaunchMetric()],
                    options: options) {
                XCUIApplication().launch()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It crashes on line `myLaunchMetric.willBeginMeasuring()` with

> Thread 2: "-[XCTApplicationLaunchMetric willBeginMeasuring]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000026c620"

---

I found that the selector error is typically caused because the instance does not have `willBeginMeasuring()` method. I also found that `MyXCTApplicationLaunchMetric`'s `init` is called once and then the `copy(with:)`, which is not clear why it would need a copy.

Comment: "I also found that MyXCTApplicationLaunchMetric's init is called once and then the copy(with:), which is not clear why it would need a copy." That's probably just due to the really weird way that xc tests work. But do note, please, that your implementation of `copyWithZone` is utterly wrong and will break things right and left; you _must_ supply a copy, not `self`. — It is not clear to me what this class of yours is for, but my advice would be, don't. You're messing around in a very tricky Objective-C area, and it is not to be messed with. It's fine to write test helpers, but this is not how.

Comment: Just wondering, but since it's an NSObjectProtocol, could you try to add `@objc` in front of `func willBeginMeasuring()` (and the other protocol methods too)?

Comment: @Cœur: Based on the error `willBeginMeasuring` in the custom object is being called, but the `XCTApplicationLaunchMetric` is not recognizing the method being called on it. Probably the issue lies with the mistaken implementation of `copy`. The error sounds like it could be a bad memory access.

Comment: @matt, I have tried simply a new instance of Self and it still errors out in the same way. I also created an init that accepts the same instance of `myLaunchMetric` so that it is copied, and it also produces an error. I do agree the issue seems to be in the `copy(with:)` part.

As for why this XCTMetric subclass: I am trying to have access to what `reportMeasurements()` returns.

Comment: Thanks. So, the crash is because `willBeginMeasuring` and `didStopMeasuring` are marked `@optional` in the protocol, and `XCTApplicationLaunchMetric` does not necessarily implement them. So remove `myLaunchMetric.willBeginMeasuring()` and maybe `myLaunchMetric.didStopMeasuring()` and it shouldn't crash anymore.

Comment: Or call them only if implemented: `myLaunchMetric.willBeginMeasuring?()`

Comment: Don't write comments like this: `// XCTMetric conformance`. Just move the protocol conformance into its own extension: `extension MyXCTApplicationLaunchMetric: XCTMetric { ... }`, and put the members in there.

Comment: I would be surprised if`XCTApplicationLaunchMetric ` does implement those two optional functions. Also, @Alexander, using `?` gives error  `Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type '() -> Void'`

Comment: @fingia Interesting. I haven't tried it with `XCTApplicationLaunchMetric` specifically, but you can _definitely_ use `method?()` to call an `@objc optional func method()`, only if it's implemented by a particular object. Not sure why it doesn't work in this case.